# Why are Xs added to data frame variable names when using read.csv?

Tags: r, dataframe, names, read.table

When I use the `read.csv()` function in `R` to load data, I often find that an X has been added to variable names.  I think I just about always see it it in the first variable, but I could be wrong.

At first, I thought `R` might be doing this because I had a space at the beginning of the variable name - I don't.

Second, I had read somewhere that if you have a variable that starts with a number, or is a very short variable name, `R` would add the X.  The variable name is all text and the length of the name of this variable is 12 characters, so it's not short.

Now, this is purely an annoyance.  I can rename the column, but it does add a step, albeit a small one.

Is there a way to prevent this from rogue X from infiltrating my data frame?

Here is my original code:

```
df <- read.csv("/file/location.filecsv", header=T, sep=",")
```

Here is the variable in question:

```
str(orders)
'data.frame':   2620276 obs. of  26 variables:
 $ X.OrderDetailID    : Factor w/ 2620193 levels "(2620182 row(s) affected)",..: 105845
```

Comment: Can you post the variable names with Xs and the code you used to read in data?

Comment: I still don't understand *why* this is happening.  The fact that it happens (mostly?) to the first variable name suggests to me that you are somehow ending up with an invisible special character at the beginnings of your files?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`read.table` and `read.csv` have a `check.names=` argument that you can set to `FALSE`.

For example, try it with this input consisting of just a header:

```
> read.csv(text = "a,1,b")
[1] a  X1 b 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

versus

```
> read.csv(text = "a,1,b", check.names = FALSE)
[1] a 1 b
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 3):

It is surprising behavior, but I think we would need a reproducible example.  Perhaps you have some invisible/special characters hiding in your file?

```
names(read.csv(textConnection(
"abcdefghijkl, a1,2x")))
```

behaves fine.  Can you make an example along these lines that demonstrates your problem?

As described in the other answer, `check.names=FALSE` is a possible workaround.  You can experiment with `make.names` to determine the behavior ...

Answer (score 3):

As Gabor said, by default `read.csv` deafults to converting the names in your header row to be valid variable names (use `check.names = FALSE` to turn this off).  This is done using the function `make.names`.  The help page for that function explains what constitutes a valid variable name.

> A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or
>   underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed
>   by a number. Names such as ".2way" are not valid, and neither are the
>   reserved words.

The list of reserved words is found on the help page `?reserved`.

The other condition is that the variable name must be 10000 characters or less, but `make.names` won't shorten it.  So be careful of being *really* verbose with your variable names.

You can check for valid variable names using

```
library(assertive.code)
is_valid_variable_name(x)
```

Comment: At an average typing speed of 200 characters per minute - thats 50 mins to type each variable name - ouch!