# Why am I getting X. in my column names when reading a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, read.csv, illegal-characters

I asked a [question about this a few months back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098245/r-why-are-xs-added-to-the-names-of-variables-in-my-data-frame), and I thought the answer had solved my problem, but I ran into the problem again and the solution didn't work for me.

I'm importing a CSV:

```
orders <- read.csv("<file_location>", sep=",", header=T, check.names = FALSE)
```

Here's the structure of the dataframe:

```
str(orders)

'data.frame':   3331575 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ OrderID  : num  -2034590217 -2034590216 -2031892773 -2031892767 -2021008573 ...
 $ OrderDate: Factor w/ 402 levels "2010-10-01","2010-10-04",..: 263 263 269 268 301 300 300 300 300 300 ...
```

If I run the `length` command on the first column, OrderID, I get this:

```
length(orders$OrderID)
[1] 0
```

If I run the `length` on OrderDate, it returns correctly:

```
length(orders$OrderDate)
[1] 3331575
```

This is a copy/paste of the `head` of the `CSV`.

```
OrderID,OrderDate
-2034590217,2011-10-14
-2034590216,2011-10-14
-2031892773,2011-10-24
-2031892767,2011-10-21
-2021008573,2011-12-08
-2021008572,2011-12-07
-2021008571,2011-12-07
-2021008570,2011-12-07
-2021008569,2011-12-07
```

Now, if I re-run the `read.csv`, but take out the `check.names` option, the first column of the `dataframe` now has an X. at the start of the name.

```
orders2 <- read.csv("<file_location>", sep=",", header=T)

str(orders2)

'data.frame':   3331575 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ X.OrderID: num  -2034590217 -2034590216 -2031892773 -2031892767 -2021008573 ...
 $ OrderDate: Factor w/ 402 levels "2010-10-01","2010-10-04",..: 263 263 269 268 301 300 300 300 300 300 ...

length(orders$X.OrderID)
[1] 3331575
```

This works correctly.

My question is why does `R` add an X. to beginning of the first column name?  As you can see from the CSV file, there are no special characters. It should be a simple load.  Adding `check.names`, while will import the name from the CSV, will cause the data to not load correctly for me to perform analysis on.

What can I do to fix this?

Side note:  I realize this is a minor - I'm just more frustrated by the fact that I think I am loading correctly, yet not getting the result I expected.  I could rename the column using `colnames(orders)[1] <- "OrderID"`, but still want to know why it doesn't load correctly.

Comment: Can you cut and paste the following outputs: `head(orders)` & `head(orders2)`?

Comment: I'm more curious to see the actual raw csv file. Can you post it somewhere and provide a link so we can download it and try to reproduce this behavior. Whatever the problem is, my guess is the answer lies in the precise structure and contents of the file.

Comment: I don't get the str of orders but then the `length(orders$OrderID) [1]0`

Comment: I'm with @joran; I imagine that there is a non-visible character at the start of the file which is being pulled into the column name (with `check.names=FALSE`) or triggering a name change (with `check.names=TRUE`). Unfortunately, a cut-and-past of the CSV probably won't show that.  What does `dput(names(orders)[1])` give? Also, if `length(orders[[1]])` gives the right value, then you know it is in the name.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`read.csv()` is a wrapper around the more general `read.table()` function. That latter function has argument `check.names` which is documented as:

> ```
> check.names: logical.  If ‘TRUE’ then the names of the variables in the
>          data frame are checked to ensure that they are syntactically
>          valid variable names.  If necessary they are adjusted (by
>          ‘make.names’) so that they are, and also to ensure that there
>          are no duplicates.
> ```

If your header contains labels that are not syntactically valid then `make.names()` will replace them with a valid name, based upon the invalid name, removing invalid characters and possibly prepending `X`:

```
R> make.names("$Foo")
[1] "X.Foo"
```

This is documented in `?make.names`:

> ```
> Details:
>
>     A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the
>     dot or underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot
>     not followed by a number.  Names such as ‘".2way"’ are not valid,
>     and neither are the reserved words.
>
>     The definition of a _letter_ depends on the current locale, but
>     only ASCII digits are considered to be digits.
>
>     The character ‘"X"’ is prepended if necessary.  All invalid
>     characters are translated to ‘"."’.  A missing value is translated
>     to ‘"NA"’.  Names which match R keywords have a dot appended to
>     them.  Duplicated values are altered by ‘make.unique’.
> ```

The behaviour you are seeing is entirely consistent with the documented way `read.table()` loads in your data. That would suggest that you have syntactically invalid labels in the header row of your CSV file. Note the point above from `?make.names` that what is a letter depends on the locale of your system; The CSV file might include a valid character that your text editor will display but if R is not running in the same locale that character may not be valid there, for example?

I would look at the CSV file and identify any non-ASCII characters in the header line; there are possibly non-visible characters (or escape sequences; `\t`?) in the header row also. A lot may be going on between reading in the file with the non-valid names and displaying it in the console which might be masking the non-valid characters, so don't take the fact that it doesn't show anything wrong without `check.names` as indicating that the file is OK.

Posting the output of `sessionInfo()` would also be useful.

Comment: Nice answer Gavin +1  I wonder if there's a space in front of the header name as `make.names(" Foo")` creates `"X.Foo"` as well.

Comment: Is it possible to use a different character instead of `X`?

Comment: A very simplified summary of this perfect answer would be, try adding this to your read.table() if you don't want R to change your names: `check.names=FALSE`

Answer (score 14):

I just came across this problem and it was for a simple reason. I had labels that began with a number, and R was adding an X in front of them all. I think R is confused with a number in the header and applies a letter to differentiate from values.

So, "3_in" became "X3_in" etc... 
I solved by switching the label to "in_3" and the issues was resolved.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  How did you systematically remove the "x." and append all the columns with "in_" ?

Answer (score 12):

When the column names don´t have correct form, R put an "X" at the start of the column name during the import. For example it is usually happening when your column names starts with number or some spacial character. The `check.names = FALSE` cause it will not happen - there will be no "X".
However some functions may not work if the column names starts with numbers or other special character. Example is `rbind.fill` function.

So after the application of that function (with "corrected colnames") I use this simple thing to get rid of the "X".

```
destroyX = function(es) {
  f = es
  for (col in c(1:ncol(f))){ #for each column in dataframe
    if (startsWith(colnames(f)[col], "X") == TRUE)  { #if starts with 'X' ..
      colnames(f)[col] <- substr(colnames(f)[col], 2, 100) #get rid of it
    }
  }
  assign(deparse(substitute(es)), f, inherits = TRUE) #assign corrected data to original name
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I ran over a similar problem and wanted to share the following lines of code to correct the column names. Certainly not perfect, since clean programming in the forehand would be better, but maybe helpful as a starting point to someone as quick and dirty approach. (I would have liked to add them as comment to Ryan's question/Gavin's answer, but my reputation is not high enough, so I had to post an additional answer - sorry).

In my case several steps of writing and reading data produced one or more columns named "X", X.1",... containing content in the X-column and row numbers in the X.1,...-columns. In my case the content of the X-column should be used as row names and the other X.1,...-columns should be deleted.

```
Correct_Colnames <- function(df) {

 delete.columns <- grep("(^X$)|(^X\\.)(\\d+)($)", colnames(df), perl=T)

  if (length(delete.columns) > 0) {

   row.names(df) <- as.character(df[, grep("^X$", colnames(df))])
   #other data types might apply than character or 
   #introduction of a new separate column might be suitable

   df <- df[,-delete.columns]

   colnames(df) <- gsub("^X", "",  colnames(df))
   #X might be replaced by different characters, instead of being deleted
  }

  return(df)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved a similar problem by including `row.names=FALSE` as an argument in the `write.csv` function. `write.csv` was including the row names as an unnamed column in the CSV file and `read.csv` was naming that column 'X' when it read the CSV file.

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes! I did not have weird symbols nor numbers in my column names but still have this issue of an "X" column created when reading csv. Your solution solved the problem perfectly! It was the row names (that I am not aware was there).