# R read.csv - header with a specific symbol(>)

Tags: r, csv

When i read a csv file through R, all specific symbols(>,<) are replaced by points(.).

for example:

csv file:
users>75

R shows users.75

How i can avoid this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [X. in my column names of an R data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441437/x-in-my-column-names-of-an-r-data-frame)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `check.names=FALSE` in your `read.csv` call.

From `?read.csv`:

> check.names: logical.  If ‘TRUE’ then the names of the variables in the
>             data frame are checked to ensure that they are syntactically
>             valid variable names.  If necessary they are adjusted (by
>             ‘make.names’) so that they are, and also to ensure that there
>             are no duplicates.