# csv read inserts an 'X' column to my loaded dataframe in R..?

Tags: r, csv

Sometimes when I load a csv using read.csv I get an extra column called X with a sequential row count as the first column. I have to remove it each time.

Does anyone know why this happens..?

```
X   Day   Who
1   Tue   Bob
2   Wed   Dan
3   Thur  Joe
```

Paul.

Comment: Perhaps the header and body row counts are off.  Try `read.csv(file, skip = 1, header = F)`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441437/x-in-my-column-names-of-an-r-data-frame

Comment: I think `read.csv(file, row.names=F)`, though you may find dplyr more handy: `dplyr::read_csv(file)`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I think I figured it out.
Did you perhaps download your CSV from excel? Sometimes, an entry in  the last column is larger than the cell of the last column. When you save the spreadsheet as a csv, somehow that overlap registers as a new column, and records a blank column called x.
The solution is to expand the final cell to accommodate it's entries. This has worked for me, as bizarre as it sounds.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well, but it was loading a different number of columns each time - depending on how many cells had overlapping text.  I solved it in excel by selecting all - format cell - shrink text to fit.