# Remove the "X" letter from the column names of a new dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to group by `year` and sum the `weight` for each `year` but when my new data frame is created the column names begin with an annoying "X" like "`X2000`" instead of `2000`. Of course I could just delete it or replace it with "" after creation but I want it not be created from the very beginning since this method will be applied to dataframes with more columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

year<-c("2000","2000","2001","2002","2000","2002")
weight<-c(0.5,0.7,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.9)
YG<-data.frame(year,weight)


w<-data.frame(YG %>%
                     group_by(year) %>%
                     summarise(n = round(sum(weight)),
                               g = n()) %>%
                     select(-g) %>%
                     spread(year, n, fill = 0))
```

Comment: The problem is you're attempting to replace colnames with numeric names. Perhaps set colnames to something non-numeric?

Comment: Why do you need to wrap with `data.frame`.  A `tibble` output is fine

Comment: For more info, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441437/why-am-i-getting-x-in-my-column-names-when-reading-a-data-frame)

Comment: I manipulate it easier later but I understand your question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While not really advisable, what you want is `check.names = FALSE` in the `data.frame` call:

```
data.frame(YG %>% group_by(year) %>%
             summarise(n = round(sum(weight)), g = n()) %>%
             select(-g) %>% spread(year, n, fill = 0), 
           check.names = FALSE)
#   2000 2001 2002
# 1    2    1    2
```

Comment: Good to know that option is there. Using `as.data.frame` (no options) also works

Answer (score 3):

An alternative: new_YG is w

```
names(new_YG)<-sapply(str_remove_all(colnames(new_YG),"X"),"[")
names(new_YG)
new_YG
```