# When we read csv in R, the numeric values come with prefix X

Tags: r, csv

I used this code below:

```r
Tmps <- read.csv(file = 'data/T.csv')
```

It gives me this output

[image: R output]

I want the output like this, This CSV file looks like below: What am I doing wrong?

[image: output file]

Comment: Use `header = FALSE` i.e `Tmps <- read.csv(file = 'data/T.csv', header = FALSE)`

Comment: You could also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441437/why-am-i-getting-x-in-my-column-names-when-reading-a-data-frame

Comment: Aren't those literals just the names of fields not the values?